# Help proving or disproving the following

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces.

Suppose $X=\bigcup_{\alpha\in\Lambda}A_\alpha$ for $\{A_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in\Lambda}$ closed in $X$, then

1. Find a function $f:X\to Y$ such that for all $\alpha\in\Lambda$, $f|_{A_\alpha}:A_\alpha\to Y$ is continuous but $f:X\to Y$ is not.
2. Suppose $\Lambda$ is a finite set, then show that given $f:X\to Y$, if for any $\alpha\in\Lambda$, $f|_{A_\alpha}:A_\alpha\to Y$ is continuous, then $f:X\to Y$ is continuous.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to math.se! Where are you having trouble? What have you tried?

Comment: To find the answer, I tried lower limit topology and another cases like usual topology and upper limit etc. But Failed to solve the above. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

1. For the first question, find a $T_1$ space $X$, a space $Y$, and a function $f:X\to Y$ that is not continuous, let $\Lambda=X$, and for each $x\in X$ let $A_x=\{x\}$.
2. For $\alpha\in\Lambda$ let $f_\alpha=f\upharpoonright A_\alpha$. Show that if $H$ is a closed subset of $Y$, then $$f^{-1}[H]=\bigcup_{\alpha\in\Lambda}f_\alpha^{-1}[H]\;,$$ and that this is a closed set in $X$.

Comment: @sehyeok: You’re welcome.